# MySQL query - Join Query

Tags: mysql

Not sure how to write this join for 2 tables.  Here is some sample data to illustrate:

```
orders
-----------------------
| order_id | customer |
-----------------------
  ABC12345   1
  ABC12346   4
  ABC12347   3
  ABC12348   2
  ABC12349   2
  ABC12350   3


customers
-----------------------------------
| id | name | email                |
-----------------------------------
  1    James  james@gmail.com
  2    Alice  alice@hotmail.com
  3    Jimbo  james@gmail.com
  4    Jim    james@gmail.com
  5    Lucy   lucy@yahoo.com
```

I have an order_id, which I already know.  Let's use the first one in the table: ABC12345.  As you can see, the customer ID is 1, so that order was placed by James.  Now sometimes James has ordered again using different names but we know it's him because of his email address.

So how do I retrieve all of James' orders based on his email address of james@gmail.com, if I know one of his order numbers (ABC12345)?

**Edit:** Not sure I stressed this enough... James has ordered 3 times, using the same email address but names of James, Jim and Jimbo.  I need all of his orders using james@gmail.com as the email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT o2.order_id
    FROM orders o1
        INNER JOIN customers c1
             ON o1.customer = c1.id -- get the customer for the first order
        INNER JOIN customers c2
             ON c1.email = c2.email -- find all customers with same email
        INNER JOIN orders o2
             ON c2.id = o2.customer -- find all orders for those customers
    WHERE o1.order_id = 'ABC12345'
```

Comment: Good one Joe, cleaner than my version, but I wonder about performance differences between the two :)

Comment: I think it's enough just one join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM orders
WHERE customer IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM customers
    WHERE email = (SELECT c.email FROM customers c JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer WHERE o.order_id = 'ABC12345')
   )
```

Comment: The OP asked a question how to retrieve this data " _if I know one of his order numbers (ABC12345)_ ". Your answer does not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first quantify the person of the order to the customer table... Then, get all customer IDs by that same email... THEN get the orders that qualify those customer IDs.

```
select o2.*
   from orders o2
      JOIN ( select c2.ID
              from customers c2
                 join ( select c1.email
                           from orders o
                              join customers c1
                                 on o.Customer = c1.ID
                           where
                              o.order_id = 'ABC12345' ) FoundTheEmail
                   on c2.email = FoundTheEmail.email 
           ) as SameCustomerEMail
         on o2.Customer = SameCustomerEMail.ID
```

Answer (score -2):

try this since james has only one order

```
SELECT orders.order_id, customers.name, customers.email 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id = orders.customer 
WHERE orders.orer_id = 'ABC12345'
```

The order ID is a UNIQUE number, then you will not have two orders with the same ID, why care about the customer name? 
"Every order will have a Customer's ID."

Comment: James really has 3 orders, he just used the name Jim and Jimbo the other times, so I need those orders too.

Comment: @Fernando Costa I have provided all the information necessary.  I think you have misunderstood the question.  I don't know the customer's email address, I only know one of their order numbers.  The data is not important, it's just as an example.

Answer (score -2):

SELECT order_id
  FROM orders
 WHERE customer IN (SELECT customer
                      FROM orders
                     WHERE order_id = 'ABC12345')

Comment: I need the query to get all of the customer's orders based on the email address.